# How to undo ALTER TABLE ... ADD PARTITION without deleting data

Tags: apache-spark, hive, partition, hive-partitions, hiveddl

Let's suppose I have two hive tables, `table_1` and `table_2`. I use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_2 ADD PARTITION (col=val) LOCATION [table_1_location]
```

Now, `table_2` will have the data in `table_1` at the partition where `col = val`.

What I want to do is reverse this process. I want `table_2` not to have the partition at `col=val`, and I want table_1 to keep its original data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your table EXTERNAL first:

```
ALTER TABLE table_2 SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
```

Then drop partition, the data will remain, only table_2 partition metadata will be deleted:

```
ALTER TABLE table_2 DROP PARTITION (col=val)
```

table_1 partition data will remain as is.